# Running .jacl scripts on WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere, wsadmin, websphere-liberty

How do I run a .jacl script against a WebService Liberty Profile server?

I am told to run:

```
wsadmin.sh -conntype none -f setupWAS.jacl
```

But I don't think wsadmin is available in Liberty Profile.

Comment: Have you tried to find the wsadmin tool yet? If there is no wsadmin tool then I don't know of any other way to run a JACL script.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot manage Liberty profile using wsadmin. Quoting [infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_scriptingep.html);

> Restriction: The wsadmin tool does not apply to the Liberty profile.
>   See [Administering the Liberty profile from the command prompt](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_admin_script.html) instead.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Is there an alternative way of applying the configuration in the .jacl file?

Comment: I don't think such a way exists, as administrative models are completely different.

Comment: I am trying to run this sample: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.samples.doc%2Fae%2Fwelcome_samples.html. Basically, is my only option to figure out how to do all the steps in the jacl file manually?

Comment: Frankly I don't think even that will be enough. Checking the list of samples, I notice they contain demonstration of some specifications that are not yet supported by Liberty profile like OSGI, contect dependency injection (CDI), Java Batch, Service Component Architecture (SCA) etc. These samples seem to be targetted for regular WAS profile and I think you can't configure Liberty for some of these samples.

Comment: OSGi applications have always been supported by the Liberty profile. CDI is supported as of 8.5.5. It is correct that Java Batch and SCA are not supported.

Comment: I swear, everytime I think I have IBM figured out they kick me when i'm down. Trying to move to liberty because traditional doesn't run on OS X. Now we gotta figure out how to do all of the wsadmin stuff manually? Avoid websphere if you can people.

Answer (score 0):

The Liberty profile only supports configuration (or reconfiguration) via editing of the XML configuration file (at least server.xml, perhaps others if you use includes).

I recommend following samples and examples from WASDev instead: 
https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/docs/category/coding/